# Unicode display incorrectly when saved to variable

Tags: powershell, unicode

[image]

I run command `git status -s --porcelain`, the Unicode characters output correctly.

If I save the command result into a variable, and display the variable, the  Unicode characters display incorrectly.

How do I fix that?

Comment: `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8`

Comment: @PetSerAl Exellent!! Can you explain a bit more how this works? Why did the git command itself work?